# jquery toggle to show hide elements on responsive design

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, toggle

I use CSS to show and hide elements at certain break points.  I also use jquery toggle to show / hide elements. If I resize my browser to mobile size, everything works, but then when I resize the browser to make bigger, the elements I have hidden using Jquery are then hidden leaving gaps in my web page.  I need a seemless way to reset to the original on window resize or change of orientation.

For example, I have a menu div that I hide with CSS for a tablet or mobile and I display a menu icon using CSS instead of the menu.  I then use Jquery to show / hide the menu when the icon is selected.  If I make the browser larger or change orientation of a mobile or tablet to landscape, the menu does not show if the user hid the menu using the icon.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on mine. This is a very simplistic version of my solution:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if($(this).width() > 800){
        $('#Menu').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

Or whatever the width is where the menu should show. This gets rid of the "show/hide" inline CSS that jQuery put in there by hitting the button.

I will say that my solution involves more components ... being in a function, and I noticed that the `.on()` handler applied a million times for the mobile version, so I have `.off()` before the `.on('click')` ... stuff like that. But the core component is to remove the style attribute that jQuery gives the menu, so that the CSS you gave it is no longer overridden.

Comment: I did try to use $(window).resize(function(){location.reload();}); but your solution is much better - thanks.